# How to change the bipartite into a normal form

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If we have a bipartite,we can change its form into a normal form like this

```
g1 = GraphData[{8, 579}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graph[g1, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But in this graph this method does not work

```
g = GraphData[{"CubicTransitive", 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graph[g, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But we can see this two both is bipartite

```
BipartiteGraphQ /@ {g1, g}
```

> {True, True}

And you can find a lot of graph cannot convert into "normal form" like this

```
{Graph[GraphData[#], GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", 
    VertexLabels -> "Name"]} & /@ GraphData["Bipartite"][[;; ;; 100]]
```

Is a bug of `Mathematica`??

Comment: Using `EdgelList@g` rather than `g` as the first argument, i.e., `Graph[EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]` gives what is expected.

Comment: @kglr It seem I post a ridiculous post.If you don't mind,I'll delete this post.:). But why we can change the `g1` like that?

Comment: it is indeed puzzling that `Graph[g1, ...]`  works in version 10 (it doesn't in v9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GraphData[{"CubicTransitive", 20}]` sets `VertexCoordinates` and `VertexCoordinates` has higher priority than `GraphLayout` (options section in [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) documentation).

```
g = GraphData[{"CubicTransitive", 20}];
Options[g]
```

> {VertexCoordinates -> {{1., 0.}, {0.5, 0.866}, {-0.5, 0.866}, {-1., 
>       0.}, {-0.5, -0.866}, {0.5, -0.866}, {1.5, 0.}, {0.75, 
>       1.299}, {-0.75, 1.299}, {-1.5, 
>       0.}, {-0.75, -1.299}, {0.75, -1.299}, {2., 0.}, {1., 1.732}, {-1.,
>        1.732}, {-2., 0.}, {-1., -1.732}, {1., -1.732}}}

```
g2 = Graph[g, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];

Options[g2]
```

> {GraphLayout -> {"Dimension" -> 2,     "VertexLayout" ->
>   "BipartiteEmbedding"},   VertexCoordinates -> {{1., 0.}, {0.5, 0.866},
>   {-0.5, 0.866}, {-1., 
>       0.}, {-0.5, -0.866}, {0.5, -0.866}, {1.5, 0.}, {0.75, 
>       1.299}, {-0.75, 1.299}, {-1.5, 
>       0.}, {-0.75, -1.299}, {0.75, -1.299}, {2., 0.}, {1., 1.732}, {-1.,
>        1.732}, {-2., 0.}, {-1., -1.732}, {1., -1.732}},   VertexLabels -> {"Name"}}